# Git : Make the same edits on two different branches at the same time

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

I would like to know if it's possible to work on two branches simultaneously if I want to write code that is supposed to be in those two branches. So that, if I commit my changes, it actually updates both branches.

For example :

The code in my **branch A** is this

```
print "I like cake"
```

And the one in my **branch B** is

```
print "I love bananas"
```

But I'd like them **both** to have this line of code :

```
print "Everyone loves stackoverflow"
```

Do I really have to write it in branch A, copy it, checkout B, and paste it ?

Can't I apply changes to two different branches ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to work on two branches simultaneously you should seriously think about why you have separate branches to begin with. Branches are usually there so you have separated commits that do not interfere with the other ones.

That being said you could† cherry-pick the commit on B, once it’s done on branch A. This will reapply the commit on the other branch. I.e. `git cherry-pick A` to pick the top commit on `A` and reapply it to the current branch.

†The problem is that it would try to add the diff, where the line `print "I like cake"` is being removed which is not present on branch B, so the patch would fail and as such also the cherry-pick, resulting in a conflict. And that actually makes sense: How exactly should Git know that those two cake/banana-love lines are actually related to each other?

Comment: Thanks. I have a large project that is supposed to work on several platforms. 90% of the code is the same, but a small part has to be adapted. I just wished I could work normally, and just have parts of my code that are different, and not having conflicts when commiting my changes. But I guess I can't ?

Comment: Usually the common approach to that is to either share the complete code base with all platform-dependent stuff (for example Python simply has a [subfolder](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/PCbuild), with all the Windows-related project files etc. necessary to build, next to the normal stuff), or to make separate platform-projects which use another (platform-independent) base-project with the common code (for example using Git’s submodules). In that case, most of your work would happen in that base project while platform-dependent stuff would only ever happen in the other ones.